# How can arp ping latency be so low? Why is it sometimes high?

Tags: usb, ethernet

```
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4436 time=130.798 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4437 time=189.399 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4438 time=4.703 msec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4439 time=191.152 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4440 time=137.136 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4441 time=192.476 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4442 time=135.642 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4443 time=195.059 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4444 time=108.263 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4445 time=176.353 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4446 time=127.711 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4447 time=182.029 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4448 time=210.172 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4449 time=182.902 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4450 time=103.740 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4451 time=190.671 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4452 time=204.851 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4453 time=163.100 usec
60 bytes from 00:01:02:03:04:05 (10.0.0.2): index=4454 time=96.656 usec
```

This `arping` output is from a host PC through an ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772 USB-to-Ethernet adapter to an STM32 board with Ethernet.

--How is latency generally under 0.2ms achieved? I thought full-speed USB devices were polled at 1ms; shouldn't the adapter be slowing things down significantly?-- This part is clear now, the adapter is a high-speed device.

What is the cause of the maximum latency (4.703ms) being >48x the minimum latency (96.656  usec)?

Comment: What makes you think that is a "full-speed" USB device?

Comment: You're right, it's a high speed device.